# Computing bounding box of polytope (system of linear inequalities)

Tags: algorithms, convex-analysis, polygons, polyhedra, discrete-geometry

Given a N real valued variables and a set of linear inequality constraints, I would like to find a minimal bounding box which encapsulates the convex polytope defined by these constraints.

I think (but am not certain) I can frame this as 2*N linear programming problems, where the constraints remain the same for each one, but the cost function is just the identity function on each variable, and I attempt to both maximise and minimise this to find the upper and lower bounds of each dimension of the box.  I could then apply any common algorithm such as the simplex algorithm.

This seems like it may be overkill however; is there a simpler way to solve this problem?

Comment: were you able to find some reasonable solution?

Answer (score 2):

A more natural approach is to enumerate the vertices of the polytope. Here is a link to an algorithmic approach: http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~avis/doc/avis/AF92b.pdf

Comment: That is a good suggestion. Let me familiarize myself again with the nuances of vertex enumeration, and see if I can summarize that algorithm.

Comment: Ok, I went into the details of the algorithm mentioned in AF92b.pdf, and it is not easily summarized in this format, or at least I tried to but don't know how to condense the algorithm's nuances in 600 characters. The backtracking in the algorithm is non-trivial, but key to the goal of full enumeration even in the presence of degenerate constraints. You got to read the paper.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{P} = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^M | Ax \le b\}$ be the polytope, for some $A \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times M}$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^N$. Then, the (tightest) bounding box is the hypercube $[\alpha_1,\beta_1] \times [\alpha_2,\beta_2] \times  \ldots [\alpha_M,\beta_M]$,  given by
\begin{equation}
\alpha_k := \underset{x \in \mathcal{P}}{\min }x_k,\text{ and }\beta_k := \underset{x \in \mathcal{P}}{\max }x_k = -\underset{x \in \mathcal{P}}{\min }-x_k.
\end{equation}

The above problems are linear programs which can be solved with your favorite solver (e.g In Python, you can use the solver scipy.optimize.linprog).

Answer (score 0):

This paper "Finding optimized bounding boxes of polytopes in d-dimensional" may help.

Michigan State University
http://www.cse.msu.edu › salman › dissertation
by S Shahid · 2014

"The starting condition is the same in this case. An axis-aligned bounding box is constructed with two adjacent edges of a regular octahedron having an angle of ..."